# Rails - Azure AD SSO error - Not found. Authentication passthru

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, azure-active-directory, devise, omniauth

I am trying to setup Azure AD SSO for my Rails app. I have followed all the steps from [this documentation](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:AzureAD).

When I click on the Login link, I see an error:

```
URL - http://localhost:3000/users/auth/microsoft?prompt=select_account

Message - Not found. Authentication passthru.
```

I tried with and without the `tenant_id` to use the `common` flow. That did not work either.

I was expecting a redirection to Azure AD for authentication and login after the authentication process.

Comment: Could you include what `omniauth` version you currently using?

Comment: @Sridevi omniauth version is `1.9.1`

Comment: You can check similar issue in this **[GitHub link](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5236)** if it helps.

Comment: @Sridevi I tried all the solutions from above link like `method: post` but still it did not work for me :(

Comment: It seems there was some cache issue or something. Today it started working without any additional changes.

Comment: Seemed to be a gem issue.  I had an additional gem in the Gemfile. Once I removed it, AD SSO started working for me.

`gem "omniauth-rails_csrf_protection", "~>0.1.2"`

Not the recommended solution. Trying to find out how to make it work with the csrf gem.